# Regex: Multiple capture groups -- search and replace - DNS Logs

Tags: regex, logging, dns, splunk, capture-group

Stummped on a regex probelem and need a hand. Basically, I have DNS logs that come in like this:

```
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E5C PACKET  000000298F0CA280 UDP Rcv 10.2.56.13      136b   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (2)25(2)21(1)5(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  000000298EE81DF0 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       7d30   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)usca-cdst-sw01(3)domain(3)com(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  00000029936FBF70 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       ce83   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)usca-edge-sw01(3)domain(3)com(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  0000002990241FD0 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       1753   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)usca-edge-sw02(3)domain(3)com(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  000000298EE81DF0 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       14b1   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)ussp-usrv-rt01(3)domain(3)com(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  00000029936FBF70 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       db29   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)usxo-core-vg02(3)domain(3)com(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  0000002990241FD0 UDP Rcv 10.2.29.29      3987   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)247(1)4(1)5(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  0000002990241FD0 UDP Rcv 10.2.29.29      0abd   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)219(2)14(1)1(2)10(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
8/21/2014 9:32:20 AM 0E60 PACKET  000000298EE81DF0 UDP Rcv 10.2.4.60       42b1   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (14)brca-rvrb-wo01(3)bru(3)domain(3)com(0)
```

Towards the end of each event, you'll see something like, "(14)ussp-usrv-rt01(3)domain(3)com(0)"

Bascially, I'm trying to write regex to convert this into "ussp-usrv-rt01.domain.com"

My strategy was to capture everything after NOERROR]\s+\w+\s+  to end of line, then replace the parenthesis with a period. Having trobule getting it just right.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Followup Question: So let's say I do this in two steps, and I'm left with this: "(14)usca-edge-sw02(3)domain(3)com(0)". How do I search and replace (xx) into a period, excluding the first and last periods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your hostnames have widely varied formats (hostnames, reversePTR names, etc..) you'd probably be better off doing it in two stages:

```
/\s(\(.*\))$/
```

to capture the `(3)216....arpa(0)` stuff, then you can use

```
implode('.' , preg_split('|\(\d+\)|', ...))
```

to explode the individual (number) bits and re-combine with `.` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm not using a programming language. I'm using splunk. I'll see if I can split it into multiple regexes though...